# Change the value of a tag only if another tag has an specific value

Tags: xslt

I'm using this xsl to change two tags of some xml

**xsl**

```
xsltproc - "filename" << EOF
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="root/attr1/text()">
      <xsl:text>new-text</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="root/group1/attr1/text()">
      <xsl:text>another-new-text</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
EOF
```

**xml**

```
<root>
  <attr1>someold</attr1>
  <group1>
    <attr1>anotherold</attr1>
  </group1>
  <attr2>0</attr2>
</root>
```

**output**

```
<root>
  <attr1>new-text</attr1>
  <group1>
    <attr1>another-new-text</attr1>
  </group1>
  <attr2>0</attr2>
</root>
```

This xsl works great for my needs but now I need to validate `attr2` before the transformation. If `attr2` is `0` I need to change, otherwise I should leave the old value.

I have hundreds of xml to convert, each one with hundreds of lines, because of this I'm looking for an automatic way to validate. I tried `xsl:if` but couldn't figure out where to place the tag and how to build the `test` attribute.

How to change the value of a tag only if another tag has an specific value? Other improvements on the xsl are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add conditions in match patterns, e.g. `<xsl:template match="root[attr2 = 0]/attr1/text()">...</xsl:match>` and/or `<xsl:template match="root[attr2 = 0]/group1/attr1/text()">`.

Comment: Is there a way to validate `attr2 = 0` just once?

Comment: Not in a template based approach, if you need two templates with the check but with different content.

Answer (score 0):

you can take the attr2 as variable and use the variable to validate your conditions.....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:variable name="attr2" select="root/attr2 "/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="root/attr1/text()">
```

```
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>

 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:text>new-text</xsl:text>
  </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="root/group1/attr1/text()">
  <xsl:text>another-new-text</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is something missing in your xsl?